# iReport Report / Subreport displays data as null

Tags: null, report, ireport

Newbie here! I've searched high and low but I cannot find an answer that makes sense to me.

I'm using iReport 4.1.1 and I want to generate a subreport containing a table using a CSV as my data source.

I can successfully generate the subreport as PDF. In other words, all the values are pulled in to the subreport when I just access the subreport by itself.

However, when I add the subreport to my main report, and generate the preview the data displays as "null".

I've seen similar questions, but haven't found any answers that work for me. I'm pretty sure that the answer to my question lies in the Properties Pane. I'm wondering if I don't quite understand the relationship between the main report, the subreport, and the data source.

Any pointers? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can look at sample: \%IREPORT_HOME%\ireport\samples\Subreports\

Comment: Another samples: http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/subreport/index.html & http://www.jasperassistant.com/forum/topic/823/simple_subreport_example_using_several?p3

Answer (score 0):

If the csv data source is a parameter to your subreport, then it should be a parameter to your main report as well.

Answer (score 0):

Data source of main report and sub report should be same. Try it.